# change vuforia video playback play icon background

Tags: android, vuforia

I am trying to change Video play icon background when a marker detected in voforia . 
by Default when detect a marker , a blank plate appear and show play icon from assests folder , i want to remove this blank plate and add video Cover instead of it ,
how can i do it .

Comment: Have you tried to replace this icon with your picture under same name?